# Pasar datos de un Activity a un Fragment

Tags: android-studio, android-fragment

agradecería vuestra ayuda para poder pasar información de un Activity a un Fragmen.

Estoy intentando pasar la ruta y en nombre de un archivo "pdf" a un fragmen para que este sea mostrado en pantalla.

Primero muestro la lista de archivos que contiene la carpeta, y desde aqui selecciono un archivo pdf para abrirlo.

**Cg_A2.java extiende de Fragment**

```
public class Cg_A2 extends Fragment {

public Cg_A2() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

View view = inflater.inflate( R.layout.cg_a2, container, false );

final ListView lv= view.findViewById(R.id.lv);
lv.setAdapter(new PDF_CustomAdapter(getActivity(),getPDFs()));

return view;
}

private ArrayList<PDFDoc> getPDFs(){
    ArrayList<PDFDoc> pdfDocs=new ArrayList<>();

    File downloadsFolder = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Documentos PDF/");

    PDFDoc pdfDoc;

    if(downloadsFolder.exists())
    {
        //GET ALL FILES IN DOWNLOAD FOLDER
        File[] files=downloadsFolder.listFiles();
        Arrays.sort(files);

        //LOOP THRU THOSE FILES GETTING NAME AND URI
        for (int i=0;i<files.length;i++)
        {
            File file=files[i];

            if(file.getPath().endsWith("pdf"))
            {
                pdfDoc=new PDFDoc();
                pdfDoc.setName(file.getName());
                pdfDoc.setPath(file.getAbsolutePath());
                pdfDocs.add(pdfDoc);
            }

        }
    }

    return pdfDocs;

}
}
```

**PDF_CustomAdapter,java que extiende de BaseAdapter**

```
public class PDF_CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context c;
ArrayList<PDFDoc> pdfDocs;


FragmentManager fragment;

public PDF_CustomAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<PDFDoc> pdfDocs) {
    this.c = c;
    this.pdfDocs = pdfDocs;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return pdfDocs.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return pdfDocs.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    if(view==null)
    {
        //INFLATE CUSTOM LAYOUT
        view= LayoutInflater.from(c).inflate(R.layout.pdf_model,viewGroup,false);
    }

    final PDFDoc pdfDoc= (PDFDoc) this.getItem(i);

    TextView nameTxt= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nameTxt);
    ImageView img= (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.pdfImage);

    //BIND DATA
    nameTxt.setText(pdfDoc.getName());
    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.pdf_icon);

    //VIEW ITEM CLICK
    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            openPDFView(pdfDoc.getPath());
        }
    });
    return view;
}

//OPEN PDF VIEW
private void openPDFView(String path)
{
   // Intent i=new Intent(c, PDF_Activity.class);
   // i.putExtra("PATH",path);
   // c.startActivity(i);

    Fragment f = new PDF_Activity_2();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putSerializable("PATH",path);
    f.setArguments(args);

    getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.pdfView,f).addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
}
}
```

**Fragment.java**

```
public class PDF_Activity_2 extends Fragment {

String path;

public PDF_Activity_2() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (getArguments() != null) {

        path = (String) getArguments().getSerializable("PATH");

    }

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pdf_activity_pdf_2, container, false);

    PDFView pdfView= rootView.findViewById(R.id.pdfView);

    //UNPACK OUR DATA FROM INTENT
    //  Intent i=this.getIntent();
    //  String path=i.getExtras().getString("PATH");

    // String path = getArguments().getString("PATH");

    //GET THE PDF_1 FILE
    File file=new File(path);

    if(file.canRead())
    {
        //LOAD IT
        pdfView.fromFile(file).defaultPage(1).onLoad(new OnLoadCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void loadComplete(int nbPages) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), String.valueOf(nbPages), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }).load();

    }

    return rootView;
    }
    }
```

**pdf_activity_pdf.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.darwindeveloper.horizontalscrollmenu.PDF_Activity">

    <com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView
        android:id="@+id/pdfView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**PDFDoc.java**

```
public class PDFDoc {
String name,path;


public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}


public String getPath() {
    return path;
}

public void setPath(String path) {
    this.path = path;
}
}
```

Como digo si alguien me puede echar una mano a resolver este problema, se lo agradecería.

Comment: Bien, desde el fragment llamas la actividad para recuperar datos de la misma? o usas la actividad haciendo cualquier tarea desde un inicio y después llamas al fragment para pasarle los datos? en que orden suceden estas acciones?

Comment: Hola @Blitz, gracias por responder, como he comentando Jesús, he cambiado el código para mostrarte lo que estoy utilizando para casar el listado de archivos y luego intentar ver uno de los pdf, no quería poner tanto código porque hay quien ve mucho y ni se molesta en leerlo.

Comment: Los muestras en un listView?

Comment: Si, es donde se cargar el contenido de una carpeta para mostrar todos los PDFs y poder seleccionar uno para mostrarlo, pero una vez selecionado o pulsado sobre uno de los pdf, no llega los datos de ese pdf que se ha seleccionado a PDF_Activity_2.

Comment: a ver, segun lo que estoy viendo no muestra el codigo de ningun activity, tendrias que tener almenos 1, en el activity es donde tienes que poner el metodo onclick que tendra que sacarlo de un boton.
Despues en el fragment aparte de oncreateView tambien tienes un motodo oncreate, en ese oncreate es donde tienes que poner lo que te digo. nose si me entiendes, pero la funcionalidad es simple
Desde el activity puedes pasar la informacion a un activity o a un fragment, a un activity lo pasas con un intent, a un fragment lo pasa con un Bundle, intentalo con eso que te digo.

Comment: Aunque la clase se llame Activity si extiendes de fragment es un fragment, para poder usar un fragment necesitas un Activity. y no veo ninguno. crea un proyecto desde 0, y comiencia con eso, creas el activity la endidad y el fragment como te he dicho

Comment: Donde tienes esto en "String path = getArguments().getString("PATH");" en la clase "PDF_Activity_2 " que en realidad es un fragment implementa el metodo oncreate como el que te tengo y recuperas los parametros, veo que estas muy muy verde intenta ver algun video que te explique algo mas detenidamente y crea un proyecto desde 0 o refactoriza los nombres de las clases y llamalas como se deben

Comment: He cambiado el codigo de arriba, no se si es correcto como lo he puesto, pero getSupportFragmentManager me muestra un error https://funkyimg.com/i/2T29y.png, en MainActivity tengo un menu horizontal, una de sus opciones muestra el Fragment con unos botones desde el que llamo al Fragmet Cg_A2 donde muestro el listado de archivos PDF y poder abrir uno, y si muy verde, por eso pido ayuda, ya casi desesperado porque he visto vídeos y vídeos la mayoría en ingles, que no lo entiendo, y vuelta a crear el código desde cero pero nada, me doy contra un muro.

Comment: y si el nombre que le he dado al Fragment PDF_Activity no es el mas correcto, este codigo lo tengo funcionando sin problemas en un Activity, y lo que hice fue copiar y pegar ese activity para probar con un fragmet y solo le cambie el nombre colocando un _2, por eso pregunto como pasar datos de un Activity a un Fragment, el querer convertir ese Activity a Fragment es porque al mostrar el PDF lo hace tampando el menu horizontal, y lo que quiero es que se muestre debajo del menu.

Comment: Bueno @jesus creo que ya lo tengo, pero cuando me muestra el pdf me lo muestra en blanco.

Comment: He cerrado la respuesta dándola por buena ya que me esta funcionando, poro como te comento, tengo un problema a la hora de visualizar el contenido del PDF, he creado un post aqui =  (https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/253290/porque-con-el-mismo-c%C3%B3digo-en-dos-app-uno-muestra-el-pdf-y-el-otro-no) por si quiere pegarle un vistazo y comentar algo por lo que pueda ser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imaginate que lo que quieres es pasar el nombre del documento y los datos al pulsar sobre un listview de documento
tendrias que tener un metodo que hiciera algo así.

```
public void onClickDoc(Documento doc) {

    Fragment f = new DetallesDocFragement();
    Bundle args = new Bundle(); //* Bundle a recibir con datos.
    args.putSerializable("doc",doc);// tendrias que poner el clase extendiendo de Serializable para poder pasar objetos enteros
    args.putString("nombre",doc.getNombre());
    args.putInt("tamaño",doc.getTamaño);
    f.setArguments(args);

    getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.contenedor,f).addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();

}
```

eso en el activiti, para poder recuperar los datos en el fragment en el oncreate es donde lo hago yo pon algo asi.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {

        nombre= getArguments().getString("nombre",null);// valor por defecto segundo parametro
        tamaño= getArguments().getInt("tamaño",null);

        doc = new Documento();
        doc = (Documento) getArguments().getSerializable("doc");


    }
}
```

ten encuenta que la variables tiene que tener declaras al principio del fragment
Un saludo espero que que te sirva
 si te fijas tienes la dos formas de pasar datos, 1 a 1 o por objetos

Comment: Hola @Jesus, gracias por responder, te dejo arriba las clases con el código completo, porque llevo todo el día intentando cambiar el código con lo que me dices,y no doy con la solución, hasta me muestra error en  getSupportFragmentManager.

Comment: Entonces que, hay alguna forma de resolver ese problema con el getSupportFragmentManager para poder probar, ahora que he puesto el codigo completo ?