# Porque con el mismo código en dos app uno muestra el PDF y el otro no

Tags: android-studio, android-fragment

no sé qué hay que comprobar para ver qué es lo que está fallando, porque es extraño que el mismo código puesto en dos proyectos desde el que muestro el listado de los pdf que contiene carpeta, en un proyecto muestre sin problemas el contenido del pdf, en cambio en el otro proyecto se abre el pdf pero lo nuestra en blanco.

**build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.1.0-beta.1'
    implementation 'com.github.GrenderG:Toasty:1.4.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation project(':horizontalscrollmenulibrary')
}
```

¿Porque se muestra el pdf en blanco?

El contenido del Logcat que muestra nada más pulsar en el pdf para verlo es el siguiente, por si alguien puede entender lo que dice para ver donde puede estar el problema.

```
2019-04-10 14:56:58.563 3619-3619/com.CirDocu.CirDocu E/com.shockwave.pdfium.PdfiumCore: Native libraries failed to load - java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.CirDocu.CirDocu-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.CirDocu.CirDocu-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.CirDocu.CirDocu-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.CirDocu.CirDocu-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.CirDocu.CirDocu-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.CirDocu.CirDocu-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.CirDocu.CirDocu-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.CirDocu.CirDocu-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.CirDocu.CirDocu-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.CirDocu.CirDocu-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.CirDocu.CirDocu-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.CirDocu.CirDocu-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.CirDocu.CirDocu-2/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]] couldn't find "libc++_shared.so"
2019-04-10 14:56:58.578 3619-3682/com.CirDocu.CirDocu E/art: No implementation found for long com.shockwave.pdfium.PdfiumCore.nativeOpenDocument(int, java.lang.String) (tried Java_com_shockwave_pdfium_PdfiumCore_nativeOpenDocument and Java_com_shockwave_pdfium_PdfiumCore_nativeOpenDocument__ILjava_lang_String_2)
2019-04-10 14:56:58.580 3619-3619/com.CirDocu.CirDocu E/PDFView: load pdf error
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for long com.shockwave.pdfium.PdfiumCore.nativeOpenDocument(int, java.lang.String) (tried Java_com_shockwave_pdfium_PdfiumCore_nativeOpenDocument and Java_com_shockwave_pdfium_PdfiumCore_nativeOpenDocument__ILjava_lang_String_2)
    at com.shockwave.pdfium.PdfiumCore.nativeOpenDocument(Native Method)
    at com.shockwave.pdfium.PdfiumCore.newDocument(PdfiumCore.java:135)
    at com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.source.FileSource.createDocument(FileSource.java:38)
    at com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.DecodingAsyncTask.doInBackground(DecodingAsyncTask.java:49)
    at com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.DecodingAsyncTask.doInBackground(DecodingAsyncTask.java:25)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:305)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

***Esto es el culpable de no ver el contenido de los PDFs***

**build.gradle**

```
packagingOptions {
exclude 'lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so'
exclude 'lib/arm64-v8a/libjniPdfium.so'
exclude 'lib/arm64-v8a/libmodft2.so'
exclude 'lib/arm64-v8a/libmodpdfium.so'
exclude 'lib/arm64-v8a/libmodpng.so'
exclude 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so'
exclude 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libjniPdfium.so'
exclude 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libmodft2.so'
exclude 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libmodpdfium.so'
exclude 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libmodpng.so'
exclude 'lib/mips/libc++_shared.so'
exclude 'lib/mips/libjniPdfium.so'
exclude 'lib/mips/libmodft2.so'
exclude 'lib/mips/libmodpdfium.so'
exclude 'lib/mips/libmodpng.so'
exclude 'lib/mips64/libc++_shared.so'
exclude 'lib/mips64/libjniPdfium.so'
exclude 'lib/mips64/libmodft2.so'
exclude 'lib/mips64/libmodpdfium.so'
exclude 'lib/mips64/libmodpng.so'
exclude 'lib/x86/libc++_shared.so'
exclude 'lib/x86/libjniPdfium.so'
exclude 'lib/x86/libmodft2.so'
exclude 'lib/x86/libmodpdfium.so'
exclude 'lib/x86/libmodpng.so'
exclude 'lib/x86_64/libc++_shared.so'
exclude 'lib/x86_64/libjniPdfium.so'
exclude 'lib/x86_64/libmodft2.so'
exclude 'lib/x86_64/libmodpdfium.so'
exclude 'lib/x86_64/libmodpng.so'
}
```

Un saludo.

Comment: Tiene toda la pinta de que te falta la libreria ``pdfium`` en el proyecto que te está dando error. ¿Has comprobado las dependencias de ambos proyectos?

Comment: Hola @Raider tengo puestas las mismas, en los dos proyecto, solo una mas en el que no muestra el pdf, que es esta `com.github.GrenderG:Toasty` que supongo que no tiene nada que ver, que es para dar colorido al Toast, salvo esta las demas estan en los dos proyectos

Comment: Es el mismo dispositivo donde se encuentran las dos aplicaciones @SoCu ?

Comment: Elenasys los estoy probando en el emulador de Android Studio

Comment: Creo que ya sé porque abre el pdf no me muestra el contenido, en **build.gracle** tengo puesto `packagingOptions` para excluir esas librerías, porque apk resultando tiene un peso exagerado (he puesto el código en el primer post)  cuando he eliminado ese apartado ya se puede ver el contenido de los pdf, pero que puedo hacer con esas librerías que crea para que no pese tanto el apk ?

Comment: No se si seguir con esto porque no se si estáis dispuesto a ayudar, pero si hay alguien que quiere echar una mano, me podéis decir porque después de no excluir esas librería se puede ver los pdf en el emulador de Android Studio y no en el móvil ? vamos que si paso ejecuto el apk en el móvil no se ven los pdf, porque ?