# ¿Como enviar datos de un activity a un fragment?

Tags: android, android-studio

Hola a todos tengo un problema, resulta que estoy haciendo un login en donde quiero Enviar datos(usuario) de ACTIVITY mediante el boton iniciar sesión a un FRAGMENT, pero no me envia ningun datos de usuario, probe con bundle, pero tampoco no me envia, no entiendo en donde me equivoque............................................................................................................................................................................................

```
public class Usuario implements Serializable{
private String Nombre;
private String Apellidos;
private String email;
private String Contrasena;

.........}
```

Esta es la Clase Activity

```
private EditText et_email, et_password;
Button btn_iniar_sesion;
TextView tv_rest;
TextView tv_registrarme;


//Arreglo Usuario
private ArrayList<Usuario> listaUsuarios;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity__login__is);
    /*NO ACTIONBAR -------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    getSupportActionBar().hide();

    /*INICIAR SESION ------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    et_email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    et_password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    btn_iniar_sesion=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    btn_iniar_sesion.setOnClickListener(this); 
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.button3:
            logIn();
    }
}

//Fill Users
private void fillUsers()
{
    listaUsuarios = new ArrayList<>();
    listaUsuarios.add(new Usuario("Jhoniors Fidel", "Falcon Andres","falcon.andres@hotmail.com", "123456"));
}


//Log In
private void logIn()
{
    fillUsers();
    String etEmail = et_email.getText().toString();
    String etContraseña = et_password.getText().toString();
    boolean usuarioEncontrado = false;
    for (int i = 0; i< listaUsuarios.size();i++)
    {
        if (etEmail.equals(listaUsuarios.get(i).getEmail()) && etContraseña.equals(listaUsuarios.get(i).getContrasena()))
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Bienvenido " + listaUsuarios.get(i).getNombre() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            usuarioEncontrado = true;
            Intent intent = new Intent(Activity_Login_IS.this,MainActivity.class);
            Activity_Login_IS.this.startActivity(intent);

            //Enviar datos al fragment
            Intent intentDatos = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UsuarioFragment.class);
            Usuario objUsuario = (Usuario) listaUsuarios.get(i);
            intentDatos.putExtra("Usuario", objUsuario);


        }
    }
    if(!usuarioEncontrado)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "El email o contraseña son incorrectos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Clase Fragment

```
public class UsuarioFragment extends Fragment {

private TextView tv_nombreCompleto, tv_email;
private Usuario objUsuario;
public UsuarioFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_usuario, container, false);
    tv_nombreCompleto = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView13);
    tv_email = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView12);

    objUsuario = (Usuario) getActivity().getIntent().getSerializableExtra("Usuario");
    if (objUsuario!=null)
    {
        tv_nombreCompleto.setText(objUsuario.getApellidos().toString());
        tv_email.setText(objUsuario.getEmail());
    }
    return view;
}
}
```

Comment: Vamos a ver, primero para pasar datos con un Intent es de un Activity a otro Activity, en tu caso no es asi, necesitaras usar Bundle, 
Un fragement tiene q ir dentro de un activity eso supongo que lo sabes
https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/251836/pasar-datos-de-un-activity-a-un-fragment/251844#251844
eso es un ejemplo de como se pasan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

creo que el problema esta en la siguientes lineas de código:

1. No puedes utilizar un `Intent` para navegar desde un `Activity` a un `Fragment`.

   ```
       Intent intentDatos = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UsuarioFragment.class);
       Usuario objUsuario = (Usuario) listaUsuarios.get(i);
       intentDatos.putExtra("Usuario", objUsuario);
   ```
2. Si deseas pasar datos desde un `Activity` a un `Fragment` existen dos posibles casos.

   2.1. El fragment hacia donde quieres enviar los datos **SI** esta dentro del mismo activity. Para este caso lo que tendrías que realizar es una "transaccion" desde el activity.

.

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
String myMessage = "Mi mensaje";
bundle.putString("message", myMessage );
UsuarioFragment userFragment = new UsuarioFragment();
userFragment.setArguments(bundle);
transaction.replace(RESOURCE_ID, userFragment);
transaction.commit();
```

2.2. El fragment hacia donde quieres enviar los datos es **NO** esta dentro del mismo activity. En este caso, primero tienes que enviar los datos hacia al `Activity` (En este caso si puedes utilizar un Intent y pasarle el bundle con los datos) y luego mandarlo hacia el fragment.

Referencia:

http://jonsegador.com/2012/02/paso-de-datos-variables-entre-actividades-android/