# ¿Como pasar datos de una activity a otra?

Tags: java, android

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación que calcula el tiempo y distancia recorrida de alguien, pero no se como podría hacer para pasar parámetros de una activity a otra.

El tiempo estaría bien con un chronometer y hay no se como pasar el tiempo determinado del chronometer cuando ya haya finalizado hacia otra activity para visualizar en esa otra activity la el tiempo y la distancia diciendo "has recorrido en tal tiempo en tal distancia" les agradecería mucho sus consejos gracias.

Comment: debes de mostrar el código java de lo que llevas, por ejemplo como obtienes el tiempo. Para pasar datos entre activities debes de buscar aqui en Stackoverflow, hay muchas respuestas

Answer (score 1):

Si es de una activity a otro se hace con un Intent, se es a un fragment con un bundle, te pongo los dos ejemplos

MainActivity

```
Intent i = new Intent(this,AntivityDondequieresDatos.class);

i.putDouble("clave",ValorCronometro);
startActivity(i);
```

para recuperar los datos en otro Activity en el metodo onCreate

AntivityDondequieresDatos

```
 Bundle b = this.getIntent().getExtras();
    if(b != null){
        double tiempo = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("clave");

    }
```

si fuera a un fragment aqui tienes un enlace
[Pasar datos de un Activity a un Fragment](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/251836/pasar-datos-de-un-activity-a-un-fragment/251844#251844)

Comment: ok, pero como recupero el valor del cronometro, por ejemplo, el tiempo acaba en 2:39, como hago para que ese tiempo pase hacia la otra actividad?

Comment: Vamos a ver, si esta puesto, para enviar los datos, en el boton, mismo insertar el codigo primero , el que pone intent i = new intent...
 y en el segundo pones el segundo trozo de codigo,, en este caso tu dato es un double, seria   double tiempo = getIntent.getDoubleExtra("clave"); la clave es la que tu pones en el intent. deberias tener un campo textView para sertar el dato y mostarlo. pon tu codigo si tienes mas dudas